# The magnetic field inside a loop

Tags: magnetic-fields

At the center of a long solenoid the Bfield is constant, but inside a single loop it is obviously not.

Do you know of any picturethat shows with colours the intensity of the field inthe various regions? is the center the strongest point or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the axis, one can shown analytically that it's strongest at the center. Off the axis, need to use computer. The result shows that, as expected, it should be strongest near the loop.
[image: Magnetic field due to a circular current loop]

Comment: Do you know an application or a software that helps constructing E & B due to arbitrary surfaces such as 2 spheres near each other or 2 plates near  a solenoid as well as the change in charge distribution on the original objects

Comment: Thanks, can you get a picture of a circular loop?

Comment: By symmetry, you just imagine rotating my picture around, you got the 3D picture of the B field due to a circular loop.

Comment: @Shashaank Sorry, I don't know of any.

Comment: @velutluna  Its Okay ! Thanks anyways.  By the way what was this maide on ?

Comment: The vector field plot is made by plotmtv.